# Как составить регулярку для RewriteRule?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Не могу разобраться, как составить регулярку для htaccess?
Нужно в ссылках символ "_" менять на "-"
Я сделал так:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*) /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

но проблема в том, что в ссылках на скачивание в именах файлов, также меняется символ "_" на "-" из-за чего возникает ошибка 404

Как написать регулярку правильно, чтоб имена файлов не обрабатывались?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^((?!.*\.(zip|rar)$).*)$ /$1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Первое правило RewriteRule проверяет, не заканчивается ли запрошенный URL-адрес на «.zip» или «.rar», используя отрицательный просмотр вперед, и если оно истинно, следующее правило не применяется. Второй RewriteRule соответствует любой строке, содержащей символ подчеркивания, и заменяет ее дефисом и перенаправлением. Необходимые расширения файлов для исключения можете добавить самостоятельно разделив вертикальной прямой `|`.